# How to capture stdout & stderr in Swift XCTest unit tests?

Tags: swift, stdout, xctest, stderr

I’m writing a command-line tool in Swift. In my unit tests, I want to test the code’s output to stdout (and, secondarily, to stderr).

The examples I’ve found of using a `Pipe()` to copy or capture stdout output mostly rely on spawning a sub-process and assigning its stdout—and I don’t know where to begin figuring out how to deal with that in XCTest. But I have managed to pull together something that sort of begins to work without spawning a separate process.

What I’ve come up with so far is compiling and running, and with an ugly hack does sort of what I need—but just for one use (if I try to use it across multiple tests in the same run, all but the first fail). The hack is that, after the calls that write to stdout, I have to add a call to write to stderr to have the data already sent to stdout then be written to my `capturedStdout` variable.

It seems there ought to be a more appropriate way to get this to work.

Here’s what I’ve got so far:

```swift
import XCTest

final class StdoutCaptureTests: XCTestCase {
    func testCapturePrint() {
        let pipe = Pipe()
        var capturedStdout = ""

        // Setup to copy data going to stdout into capturedStdout.
        setvbuf(stdout, nil, _IONBF, 0)
        // Assign stdout’s pointer to the pipe:
        dup2(pipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO)
        // A closure for receiving the data sent to stdout:
        pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { handle in
            if let str = String(data: handle.availableData, encoding: .utf8) {
                capturedStdout += str
            }
        }

        // The subject of the test outputs to stdout:
        // (In this simplified example, just print "test" to stdout.)
        print("test")

        // Here’s where it gets weird...
        // If none of the following lines are uncommented,
        // the XCTAssertEqual test below will fail
        // (nothing gets written to capturedStdout).
        // Uncommenting the following line makes the XCTAssertEqual work:
        //XCTAssert(false) // ⚠️
        // (but that means the test is considered failed.)
        // And this has no effect:
        //XCTAssert(true) // 
        // fflush has no effect (when it gets nil as argument here,
        // the man(ual) page says it “flushes all open streams.”)
        //fflush(nil) // 
        // But this works and lets the test pass:
        //FileHandle.standardError.write("".data(using: .utf8)!) // ✅

        XCTAssertEqual(capturedStdout, "test\n")
        // When the above commented lines are still commented:
        //  XCTAssertEqual failed: ("") is not equal to ("test")
    }
}
```

Given that it fails when used in subsequent test methods in the same run, I’m thinking there’s probably some cleanup I should be doing at the end of each test to restore stdout before the next test method is run.

Some of the references I’ve found:

- [using pipe() in Swift App to redirect stdout into a textView (only runs in simulator, not native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978091/using-pipe-in-swift-app-to-redirect-stdout-into-a-textview-only-runs-in-simul)
- [Redirect Process stdout to Apple System Log Facility in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638753/redirect-process-stdout-to-apple-system-log-facility-in-swift)
- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/redirecting-output-to-a-log-file-when-not-attached-to-debugger/5766

Comment: Why not refactor the code so you have one method that returns the string and one that simply prints it and then test only the first method? Testing that the returned value is right must be more important than testing that output to stdout works.

Comment: If you want to intercept data before reinjecting it into anoher process, you have to implement correctly the Pipe. So, why don't you use a `Pipe()` for `input` too?

Comment: @Larme My code isn’t touching stdin. It takes args on the command-line, does some processing, and spits out results on stdout (and sometimes stderr, if there are problems encountered). In any case, piping stdin won’t help me capture what goes to stdout.